# How to get all members from my discord py server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, discord, discord.py

I want to get all the members of my server, but when I Googled it, I just found that this code snippet would do this:

```
for guild in client.guilds:                      
 for member in guild.members:                     
  print(member)
```

Well, this code should display all members, the problem is that it only displays my bot user. But when I put it this way:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def counter():                                                                           
for guild in client.guilds:                      
 for member in guild.members:                     
  print(guild.members)
```

it displays information inside this object `[ ]` and I won't show it exactly because inside this object it has information about my account and discord server, so how can I change this code so that it shows me the number of members or the names of the members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how the member count is inside the object [ ] as I pointed out in the question, I accessed the property of this object, and then I managed to get all the members, this was the code:

```
for guild in client.guilds:
 print(guild.member_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Printing `guild.member` returns a `discord.Member` object which has a lot of information inside it. Here are the ways you would like to opt:

#### Getting count of members:

```py
for guild in client.guilds:
    print(len(guild.members))
```

#### Getting member names:

```py
for guild in client.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        print(member.name)
```

Also I would suggest reducing loop time to avoid getting ratelimited.

Comment: Hello, your code gives me the same result, I have 3 users on my server, me, my bot, and a friend, but my bot only counts itself, it doesn't count my user and my friend, and it doesn't display the name, the result for the first code of your answer is 1, and it should be 3, because I have 3 users on my server including the bot, and the second code in your answer, it displays the username of my code, not displays mine and my friend, why does this happen?

Comment: It seems like you haven't enabled intents for your bot, read this guide about enabling them: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: It wasn't enabled, but I enabled it and even so when I try to display the username it only displays the username of my own bot, instead of all members, how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you enable in the code and dev portal as well? You need to add `client.intents = discord.Intents.all()` when declaring your `commands.Bot` and then enable from the dev portal.

Comment: `client = commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents.all(), **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct which is:

```py
for guild in client.guilds:
    print(guild.member_count)
```

But as you can see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20members#discord.Guild.member_count) in the docs

> Due to a Discord limitation, in order for this attribute to remain up-to-date and accurate, it requires Intents.members to be specified.

Therefore, you must enable member intents in code and enable privileged intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

#or 
intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Member intents are used for the following: [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20members#discord.Intents.members)

This corresponds to the following events:

> - on_member_join()
> - on_member_remove()
> - on_member_update() (nickname, roles)
> - on_user_update()
>
> This also corresponds to the following attributes and classes in terms
> of cache:
>
> - Client.get_all_members()
> - Guild.chunk()
> - Guild.fetch_members()
> - Guild.get_member()
> - **Guild.members**
> - Member.roles
> - Member.nick
> - Member.premium_since
> - User.name
> - User.avatar (User.avatar_url and User.avatar_url_as())
> - User.discriminator